# integrating uppercut and cc.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, revision, build-numbers

I am trying to integrate uppercut and cc.net for getting build and revision...
What do I have to put in the `codebuild` folder?

while running cc.net, I'm getting

> svn folder Unable to execute file [D:\CodeBuild\abc\svn]. 
>   The file may not exist or may not be executable. --->
>    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Without cc.net integration can we get both build and revision incremented?

When will build and revision get incremented?

Answer (score 0):

It expects subversion to be on the command line. It's one of the requirements of UppercuT, that you can open a command line and type svn and have it execute subversion commands. In other words, that svn is on the PATH.